# Golang tcp client binary data

Tags: python, golang

Вкратце код такой:

```
outBuffer := []uint8{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
inBuffer := []uint8{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
conn, _ := net.Dial("tcp", "192.168.23.201:8103")
conn.Write(outBuffer)
count, err := conn.Read(inBuffer) //bufio.NewReader(conn).Read(inBuffer)
conn.Close()
```

И все бы хорошо, но напрягает меня такая инициализация входного и выходного буфера. Мне бы надо outBuffer := [16]uint8{}, но сконвертить его в []byte не получается.
С Go буквально пару дней вожусь и вопрос ламерский наверное, но гуглинг не помогает. Все хотят вебы, а мне надо отправить 16 байт и получить 16 байт в ответ. 
Если рассматривать более общуу задачу, то мне интересно, лучше ли Go для написания низконагруженного клиента работающего по TCP и UART для управления устройствами. Сейчас клиент на питоне и есть от него некоторая неудовлетворенность.
Заранее всем спасибо.

Comment: А как конвертите в `byte`?

Comment: А в том и проблема, что никак не конверчу. Используется объявление: outBuffer := []uint8{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0}
А хочется: outBuffer := [16]uint8{}
А вот сконвертить [16]uint8{} в []uint8 ХЗ как

Comment: А стандартно `uint8(OutBuffer)`?

Comment: Вполне логично, что
./main.go:40: cannot convert outBuffer (type [16]uint8) to type uint8
./main.go:40: cannot use uint8(outBuffer) (type uint8) as type []byte in argument to conn.Write
[]uint8(outBuffer), что более как бы тоже не работает.
*outBuffer дает ссылку на *[16]uint8, что тоже вроде как логично.
Да и фиг с ним на 16 байтах, а если мне потребуется пакет в 512 байт? Или больше.

Comment: Какая кака этот сайт - как можно рушить форматирование на айтишном ресусе?

Comment: А на соседнем - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11924196/convert-between-slices-of-different-types?

Comment: Похоже на то. Пойду разбираться. Куда поставить плюсик непонятно, но большой искренний пасип :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Разница типов

Дело в том, что массив *(array)* - это не срез *(slice)*. Компилятор сообщает именно об этом. [Пример отличий на play.golang.org](http://play.golang.org/p/9wCReC3L90). В Go типы `uint8` и `byte` эквиваленты - между ними преобразования никакие не нужны, как и не нужны преобразования между `[]uint8` и `[]byte`. Вся суть в том, что

```
x := [16]uint{} // - это массив, у него постоянный размер
y := make([]uint, 16) // - это срез длиной 16 элементов
z := []uint{0,0} // - это тоже срез
w := [...]uint{0,0,0} // - а это опять массив длиной 3 элемента
```

Для создания больших срезов используется [`make`](http://godoc.org/builtin#make)

```
x := make([]uint8, len, cap)
```

len - это длина (количество элементов)
cap - это ёмкость, то же количество - но только зарезервированное, обращаться к ним нельзя

Но есть так же и способ создавать срезы следующим образом:

```
x := []byte{0,0,0} // что эквивалентно make([]byte, 3)
```

Например

```
x := make([]byte, 0)
y := make([]byte, 0, 16)
z := make([]byte, 2, 34)
w := make([]byte, 96)
```

[Код о длине и ёмкости на play.golang.org](http://play.golang.org/p/eTOdsaR0Io). 
Вся суть в различии типов `[23]byte` и `[]byte` - одно массив, а другое срез.
Кстати вот так

```
r := [16]byte{} // массив
z := r[0:len(r)]  // срез
```

можно получить из массива срез. Хотя проще просто `r[:]`, что то-же самое.

---

#### Небольшое пояснение про отличия массивов и срезов

Массив - это последовательность данных определённого фиксированного размера. Срез это некая структура вида

```
type sliceOfT struct {
    dataPtr *T
    len     int
    cap     int
}
```

В этой структуре `dataPtr` есть указатель на массив. И вовсе не обязательно на первый элемент.

---

#### Семантика

Следуя семантике стоит называть тип `[]uint8` когда речь идёт о срезе маленьких беззнаковых целых. Если речь о данных, то рекомендуется использовать `[]byte`, что значит данные.